# Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Protractor/jamine error message:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined

any clue on whats causing this error message?

Answer (score 2):

More details would have helped.At-least what caused the error:)
But I have faced this issue before and you will see this when using `isElementPresent()` in scenarios like below

```
    expect(body.isElementPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

The problem is that isElementPresent() is checks based on subLocator and doesnt accept null as argument

The [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent) state the proper way of using it

> This checks whether the element identified by the subLocator is
>   present, rather than the current element finder

```
element(by.css('#abc')).isElementPresent(by.css('#def')).
```

Comment: That's a good guess, interesting to know if this is what happened in the OP's case.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get what you meant by OP's case

Comment: OP = Original Poster (just in case someone else should stumble upon this post)